# Infopath forms to SharePoint forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, infopath

I am new to Infopath,
I have a list in SharePoint 2010, which uses Infopath to create/edit items.

I am creating same list in SharePoint 2013 but in this environment we are not using Infopath but regular SharePoint forms.

What I tried is, I saved the list as list template. Imported in new environment created list with list template. But when I am trying to create or view existing item, I get error.

What I want to acheive is, I want same list structure with data and create item with same type of fields in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your steps but there was no error in SharePoint 2013.

Steps:

1. Save a SharePoint 2010 custom list with InfoPath form as the list template. And include content in this template.
2. Download the .stp file from the list template gallery from SharePoint 2010.
3. Upload the .stp file to the list template gallery in SharePoint 2013.
4. Create a list based on this template in SharePoint 2013.
5. Create/view the item in the SharePoint 2013 list, it displays as expected and the InfoPath form still works.

Some questions about your issue:

1. What kind of list are you using, task, custom or survey list?
2. What are the version of your SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013?
3. What the browser are you using? Test it in IE 32-bit.
4. What is the detailed error message?

Here are [several methods (demos) to migrate list from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html). Check this article to learn more about how to do that.